# Why do dig, host and nslookup return different results?

Tags: domain-name-system, host, nslookup, dig

It seems my default (router) DNS server returns different results depending on the tool used to query it.

1. Using `dig`:

   ```
   $ dig @192.168.1.2 test.example.com

   ; <<>> DiG 9.16.8-Debian <<>> @192.168.1.2 test.example.com
   ; (1 server found)
   ;; global options: +cmd
   ;; Got answer:
   ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 58608
   ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

   ;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
   ; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
   ;; QUESTION SECTION:
   ;test.example.com.    IN  A

   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   test.example.com.  41  IN  CNAME  123.123.12.123.

   ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
   .      3357  IN  SOA  a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020112400 1800 900 604800 86400

   ;; Query time: 0 msec
   ;; SERVER: 192.168.1.2#53(192.168.1.2)
   ;; WHEN: Tue Nov 24 10:12:40 CET 2020
   ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 148
   ```

As you can see, it successfully finds the IP address of `test.example.com`, which is `123.123.12.123`. However, the following two tools do not.

2. Using `host`:

   ```
   $ host test.example.com 192.168.1.2
   Using domain server:
   Name: 192.168.1.2
   Address: 192.168.1.2#53
   Aliases: 

   Host test.example.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
   ```
3. Using `nslookup`:

   ```
   $ nslookup test.example.com 192.168.1.2
   Server:    192.168.1.2
   Address:  192.168.1.2#53

   ** server can't find test.example.com: NXDOMAIN
   ```

What is going on here? Why is there a difference between the results of `dig`, `host`, and `nslookup`? Don't they all perform the same DNS queries under the hood?

*Edit: as [the accepted answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1043704/203483) points out, I incorrectly used a `CNAME` instead of an `A` record. I have since updated the DNS entry and now the domain name resolves correctly.*

*Edit2: domain and IPs are fake*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Defining this:

```
test.example.com.       IN  A 123.123.12.123
```

would be correct.

This:

> ```
> test.example.com.    41  IN  CNAME   123.123.12.123.
> ```

is invalid. A CNAME must point to an entry that appears on the left: a name, not an IP address.

Here the IP address and its final dot is taken as a name anyway, that's why the authority section refers to a root DNS server *a.root-servers.net.*, because even the lowest part (which would be 123.) can't be found according to it.

So the first command (`dig`) reports the answer it got while *also* telling NXDOMAIN, while the two other commands can't resolve the final result and just tell NXDOMAIN.

Comment: Indeed, a `CNAME` RR has a name-typed value and the problem occurring here is that the `104.248.81.197.` value is "clearly" an all-numeric *name* (not an IP address!), and this all-numeric name does not resolve to any IP address.

Comment: Yes I'll add this in the answer

Comment: btw: OP corrected the entry, it now resolves correctly.

Comment: And because the CNAME it points to is faulty, all three tools return `NXDOMAIN`. `dig` just returns the entire answer section as well, which shows the bad answer.